# HTML,javascript: on button click validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate(if they have value) my 1st two dropdowns of my html . On click of button `getURL` I am validating if there are any selected values in dropdowns and if YES I would like to proceed to `function getURL`. 
But soon after validation , the control is not stopping if there are no values in 2nd dropbox. Its going ahead and displaying the `URL`.
I would like to display `URL` only if there are values in 1st two dropdowns. But now with my below code I am getting `alert:url` soon after `alert:select product version`

Javascript:

```
function validate() {
    var pname = document.getElementById("selProductName");
    if(pname.selectedIndex == 0) {
         alert('select product name');
    }

    var pversion = document.getElementById("selProductVersion");
    if(pversion.selectedIndex == 0) {
         alert('select product version');
         return false;
    }
  return true;
}

function getURL() {         
    validate();
    // I have code here to create desired URL
    alert("url:" + url);
}
```

HTML:

```
Product Name:
<select id="selProductName" name="selProductName" onchange="changeProductName(this.value);">
<option>--Choose Product Name--</option>
</select>
<br>Product Version:
<select id="selProductVersion" name="selProductVersion" onchange="changeProductVersion(this.value);">
</select>
<br>File Name:
<select id="selFileName" name="selFileName"></select>
<br><button onclick="getURL()">Get URL</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validate()` executes and returns false. Good. And then? Then the script goes on and alerts the url.

Currently :

```
function getURL() {         
    validate(); // Returns true or return false, no consequence.
    alert("url:" + url); // Always happens.
}
```

You should use :

```
function getURL() {         
    if(!validate()) return; // Blocks execution if validation fails.
    alert("url:" + url);
}
```

Comment: I have the change and validate function is working as expected, but now my code after the line `if(!validate()) return;` is not working, when I click `GetURL`

Comment: Precisely. It means it's working. That's the idea if the validation fails. Try to `console.log( validate() )` before that line, if it logs `false` then the getURL() function will stop.

Comment: I have added a statement `return true` at end of validate function and now its working fine. thanks!

Comment: Right, that was missing. And also, add `return false` after `alert('select product name');`

Answer (score 0):

Your validate function is working exactly how it should. The problem is that you are never checking to make sure that validate didn't return false. Instead, you are just printing the url even if validate() does return false. Here is an edited version of the getURL() function that should work.

```
function getURL() {         
    var isValid = validate();
    // Code to create URL

    // Only alert the formed URL if isValid doesn't equal false
    if(isValid != false) alert("url:" + url);
}
```